# Flutter throwing an error when validating form

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

this is the error its giving me
**_formKey.currentState.*validate* : validate is getting the error**
and it wants me to use null check

> The method 'validate' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  moveToHome(BuildContext context) async{
    if(_formKey.currentState.validate())
    {
      setState(() {
        onLog = true;
      });
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 700));
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyRoutes.homeRoute);
      setState(() {
        onLog = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

its also giving me same with my text form field in validator property

```
TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Enter username',
                      labelText: 'Username',
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      uid = value;
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    validator: (value) => value.isEmpty? 'Email cannot be empty' : null,
                  )
```

in validator property **isEmpty** is also suggesting to use null check

**My whole code for clear understanding**

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  String uid = "";
  bool onLog = false;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  moveToHome(BuildContext context) async{
    final f = _formKey.currentState;
    // if(f.validate())
    {
      setState(() {
        onLog = true;
      });
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 700));
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyRoutes.homeRoute);
      setState(() {
        onLog = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Image.asset(
              'asset/image/welcome_logo.png',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Text(
              'Hi, $uid',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 28,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16, horizontal: 36),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Enter username',
                      labelText: 'Username',
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      uid = value;
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    validator: (value) => value == null ? 'Email cannot be empty' : null,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Password', hintText: 'Enter password'
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if(value == null){
                        return 'Please enter password!';
                      }else if(value.length <6){
                        return 'password must be at least 6 characters';
                      }
                      return value;
                    },
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () => moveToHome(context),
                    child: AnimatedContainer(
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                      width: onLog ? 50 : 150,
                      height: 50,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: onLog
                          ? Icon(
                              Icons.done,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            )
                          : Text(
                              'Login',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.cyan,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(onLog ? 50 : 8),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                  // ElevatedButton(
                  //     onPressed: () =>{
                  //       Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyRoutes.homeRoute),
                  //     },
                  //     child: const Text('Login'),
                  //     style:TextButton.styleFrom(minimumSize: Size(140, 40)),
                  // )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: use `_formKey.currenState!.validate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Concerning GlobalKey.currentState

From `GlobalKey.currentState` documentation:

> The current state is null if (1) there is no widget in the tree that matches this global key, (2) that widget is not a [StatefulWidget], or the associated [State] object is not a subtype of `T`.

So if you respect those conditions (which I can not deduce from what you have shared), you can safely use the `!` operator to ignore the nulability of `GlobalKey`.

### Concerning validator.value

This is due to the fact that `TextFormField` inherent from `FormField` which itself can have a null initial value. However if you look at the implementation of `TextFormField` is never null (since the default value is set to `''` if `null` is given). Therefore here you can use the `!` operator safely.

### Null safety in general

If you are having trouble understanding the concept of null safety in its own, I would advise you to do some research since this is a vast but powerful concept. Here is somewhere you could start: https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: inside widget Form( key: _formKey), and yes its inside a stateful widget but i dont know whats subtype of T; i am new to flutter

Comment: i have submitted my full code

Comment: Concerning the GlobalKey, you are all set, FormState is indeed the class that should be provided to it. Concerning the validator.value have you read my answer? Checking if null does not make sense, you should assume there are never null and check whether they are empty (value!.isEmpty ? ' Email cannot be empty' : null). Also do you understand the meaning of the ! operator? If not I urge you to look at the link I provided towards understanding null safety.

Comment: oh ok it did work now, it was giving me an error first when i was using _formKey.currentState!.validate, now it works using this code. thanks!!!